# view data from different folder in laravel-8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

[There are two folders named products and teambatter see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbFAw.png)

[Here you can see I can view name in teambatter/show.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRVeg.png)

I want to show the same name from temabatter/show to in products/indexpublic.blade.php but I don't know how to do it.

This is my indexpublic.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>খেলার স্কর</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{-- @extends('layouts.app') --}}
    @extends('products.layout')

    <nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
        <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
                {{-- <div class="flex">
                    <a href="/">hi</a>
                </div> --}}
                <div class="flex">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
                        <a href="/">
                            <x-jet-application-mark class="block h-9 w-auto" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                        <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('products.create') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('products.index')">
                            {{ __('ধারাবর্ষ') }}
                        </x-jet-nav-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                        <x-jet-nav-link href="/" :active="request()->routeIs('products.index')">
                            {{ __('স্কোর বোর্ড') }}
                        </x-jet-nav-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                        <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('projects.index') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('products.index')">
                            {{ __('Step 3') }}
                        </x-jet-nav-link>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                        <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('projects.index') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('products.index')">
                            {{ __('Step 4') }}
                        </x-jet-nav-link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {{--  --}}
    @section('content')

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <div class="col-2" style="color: #1d2124">
                <tr>
                    <th>ব্যাটসম্যান</th>
                    <th>রান</th>
                    <th>বল</th>
                    <th>ছক্কা</th>
                    <th>চার</th>
                    <th>স্ট্রাইক রেট</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ $product->name }}</td>
                    <td> {{ $product->runs }}</td>
                    <td> {{ $product->balls }}</td>
                    <td> {{ $product->sixs }}</td>
                    <td> {{ $product->fours }}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($product->runs > 0 and $product->runs ==0)
                            {{ $product->runs*100 }}
                        @elseif ($product->balls>0 and $product->runs ==0)
                            {{ $product->balls*$product->runs }}
                        @elseif ($product->balls==0 and $product->runs ==0)
                            {{ $product->balls * $product->runs }}
                        @elseif ($product->runs>0 and $product->balls>=0)
                            {{ $product->runs/$product->balls*100 }}
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </table>
        {!! $products->links() !!}
    @endsection
</body>
</html>
```

This is my ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
         $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);

         return view('products.index',compact('products'))
         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);


    }

    public function indexpublic()
    {
         $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
         return view('products.indexpublic',compact('products'))
         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);

    }

    function authapi(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User:: where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            return response([
                'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
            ],404);
        }

        $token = $user -> createToken('my-app-token')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response,201);
    }

    function all_app_jsons(){
        return User::find(auth()->user()->id)->getProducts;
    }

    function search_by_name($name){
        return Product::where('name','like','%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }

    function search_by_id($id){
        return Product::where('id',$id)->
        where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'runs' => 'required',
            'balls' => 'required',
            'sixs' => 'required',
            'fours' => 'required',
        ]);

          $input = $request->all();
        Product::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }


    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }

    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'runs' => 'required',
            'balls' => 'required',
            'sixs' => 'required',
            'fours' => 'required',
        ]);
        $product->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }

}
```

This is my TeambatterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Teambatter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TeambatterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $teambatter = Teambatter::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('teambatters.index',compact('teambatter'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('teambatters.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        Teambatter::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('teambatter.index')
                        ->with('success','Teambatter created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Teambatter  $teambatter
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Teambatter $teambatter)
    {
        return view('teambatters.show',compact('teambatter'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Teambatter  $teambatter
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Teambatter $teambatter)
    {
        return view('teambatters.edit',compact('teambatter'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Teambatter  $teambatter
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Teambatter $teambatter)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $teambatter->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('teambatter.index')
                        ->with('success','Teambatter updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Teambatter  $teambatter
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Teambatter $teambatter)
    {
        $teambatter->delete();

        return redirect()->route('teambatter.index')
                        ->with('success','Teambatter deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question. It's not clear what you are really want to.

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is? What is keeping you from showing the name?

Comment: if i do {{ $teambatter->name }} on indexpublic.blade.php i got error Undefined variable $teambatter (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp - 1.0.2\resources\views\products\indexpublic.blade.php)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by Call model in methode

```
public function indexpublic()
{
  $teambatter = Teambatter::latest()->paginate(20);
  $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
  return view('products.indexpublic',compact('products', 'teambatter'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```